# graph.facebook output in a object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to convert the information I receive Facebook from a Facebook graph request to an object but so far the only thing I did was put all the information in one large string. Is there a better way to put the whole URL in to an object so its accessible like `object.Name`? This is my javascript code to get the URL code and put it in an object:

```
var json = $.ajax({
    'url': "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=name,email,birthday,location&access_token=xxxxcallback=?"
});
```

When I say `json.responseText` I get this output in one string:

```
'{
   "name": "MY_NAME",
    "email": "MY_EMAIL",
    "birthday": "MY_BIRTHDAY",
    "location": {
        "id": "XXXX",
        "name": "MY_LOCATION"
    },
    "id": "MY_ID"
}'
```

I need this code to put it on my website for the registration page so that I can access the values easily. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you access the response of the AJAX request through any of the standard jQuery methods, such as the `success` property of `$.ajax` or `done()` of the returned deferred object then the responseText will be automatically deserialised for you. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=name,email,birthday,location&access_token=xxxxcallback=?",
    success: function(data) {
       // access the properties of the response here:
       console.log(data.name);
       console.log(data.email); 
       console.log(data.location.name);
    }
});
```

Also note that Facebook have a Javascript SDK which also provides the above functionality as well as providing some other OAuth helpers. It may be worth looking in to.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.